# Coordinate charts on a flag manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, twistor-theory

I'm trying to prove that the flag $F_{d_1\ldots d_m}(V)=\{(S_1,\ldots,S_m)|S_1\subset S_2\subset\ldots S_m \ \ \ \ \textrm{with} \ \ \ \ \textrm{dim}S_i=d_i \ \ \ \ \textrm{and}\ \ \ 1<d_1<\ldots<d_m<n\}$ where $V$ is a complex vector space od dimension $n$ and $d_i$ fixed $\forall i=1,\ldots,m$, is a smooth manifold.

I'm using the following construction of the flag manifold: Let $GL(d_m,\mathbb{C})$ and take the subgroup of upper-triangular block matrices $U(d_m)$ where the blocks o the digonal are of sizes $d_1\times d_1, (d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1),\ldots, d_m-d_{m-1}$, we will considerer the flag manifold $F_{d_1\ldots d_m}$ as the quotient space $GL(d_m,\mathbb{C})/U(d_m)$.

This construction is similar as the way we construct the Grassmanian, I tried to imitate that construction with $m=2$. I took the matrix
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}[cc]
&A_{d_1\times d_1}&A_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}\\
A_{(d_2-d_1)\times d_1}&A_{(d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1)}\\
A_{(n-d_2)\times d_1}&A_{(n-d_2)\times(d_2-d_1)}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Where $A_{i\times j}$ is a block matrix of size $i\times j$. Then I took the matrix
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}[cc]
&A_{d_1\times d_1}^{-1}&B_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}\\
0&A_{(d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1)}^{-1}\end{array}\right]
$$
Since $B$ is an upper-tringulr block matrix, we have tht $AB\sim A$, therefore
$$
A\sim AB=\left[\begin{array}[cc]
&I_{d_1\times d_1}&A_{d_1\times d_1}B_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}+A_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}A_{(d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1)}\\
A_{(d_2-d_1)\times d_1}A_{d_1\times d_1}^{-1}&A_{(d_2-d_1)\times d_1}B_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}+I_{(d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1)}\\
A_{(n-d_2)\times d_1}A_{d_1\times d_1}^{-1}&A_{(n-d_2)\times d_1}B_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}+A_{(n-d_2)\times(d_2-d_1)}A_{(d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1)}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now the only thing I can see from here is that
$$
A\sim\left[\begin{array}[cc]
&I_{d_1\times d_1}&A_{d_1\times d_1}B_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}+A_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}A_{(d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1)}\\
A_{(d_2-d_1)\times d_1}A_{d_1\times d_1}^{-1}&A_{(d_2-d_1)\times d_1}B_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}\\
A_{(n-d_2)\times d_1}A_{d_1\times d_1}^{-1}&A_{(n-d_2)\times d_1}B_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}[cc]
&0&0\\
0&I_{(d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1)}\\
0&A_{(n-d_2)\times(d_2-d_1)}A_{(d_2-d_1)\times(d_2-d_1)}\end{array}\right]
$$
If in the second column of the first matrix all the entries are zero, then I would have a parametrization of the flag. But first I don't know how to do it and second, if I find the way I would lose the element $A_{d_1\times(d_2-d_1)}$, so the maps wouldn't be injective.

Amy suggestion on how to find the charts of the flag manifolds?

Comment: Your definition at the beginning is not quite right. You need to specify that $\dim S_i = d_i$ is fixed, with $1\le d_1<d_2<\dots d_m<n$, right?

Comment: Yes. that's correct.

Comment: I already idited.